# Dealing with utf8 using char *

Tags: c, string, utf-8

Is there any c library that deals with utf8, using `char*`?
In particular, for all the `char*`, we will use utf8 compatible functions to deal with them:
counting length, comparing, find & replace, concatenation, toupper tolower etc.
There is no need to deal with conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... then the [ICU library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/utf-8) is just what you need.

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware that ICU could work directly with UTF-8. I thought it was part of the Java-UTF-16-think hegemony. :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative library is [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

I've had only modest experience with libiconv, but that experience was not painful; I can recommend it.

That library is focused on converting between encodings, including UTF8.  Though I'm not *completely* sure what you mean by 'no need to deal with conversion', I suspect that you're looking for a library which will read in encoded unicode, and then manipulate it.  If that is indeed the case, libiconv is not what you're looking for, and I second the recommendation of ICU.

Comment: `iconv` is part of the standard library on POSIX systems; the `libiconv` you're referring to is only for use on legacy systems that lack this standard feature. It also doesn't really meet OP's aim to work directly with strings in UTF-8; it's for converting them to other encodings.